# Onclick does not pass Id or Element

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick, getid3

I'm trying to pass the element or even the Id of the element over to my javascript function. I can not find my error. I did test to make sure the Onclick does go inside my JS function.

This is the Onclick html link:

```
<div class="true">
  <a class="tflink" id="q2t" href="#" onclick="check(this)">True</a>
</div>
```

This is my JS function:

```
function check(e)
{
    alert(e.Id);
}
```

Comment: Case matters, it's `e.id` in all lowercase

Comment: That is the problem..Thank you very much....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's supposed to be `e.id` not `e.Id`

so it should look like this:

```
function check(e)
{ alert(e.id);}
```